# Under Windows, what is the best way to format a drive on each boot?

Tags: windows, format

I have an SSD I use as a cache drive for a few different applications. Rather than manually clean it all the time, I think it'd be nice to have the drive be formatted at boot time, since the applications in questions automatically recreate the directories they need at startup.

I'm aware I can make a powershell or batch script that simply calls `format X: /q` at bootup. This is my plan, assuming no one here has better suggestions, which brings me to my main question: **I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way.** Namely,

1. Can I format the drive/partition by GUID, rather than by drive letter? This way, I can ensure that it'll never format the wrong drive if drive letter settings get mangled somehow.
2. Is there a filesystem whose drivers auto-wipe on startup, perhaps specifically for caching applications? This isn't required, it's more of a curiosity or a "right tool for the job" sort of thing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will significantly reduce the lifespan of your SSD.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you think you need to clear these caches all the time?

Comment: @LPChip How? If you're overwriting a handful of blocks at the start of a partition, once or twice a day at most, it can't possibly be any worse than typical uses would be on any other SSD.

Comment: Formatting the disk will make an SSD run trim on everything, touching every single block on the SSD rather than only the few blocks that contained data.